# Доверительный интервалы в python

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, статистика

Подскажите, почему в функции используется (1 + confidence) / 2. ? Можете привести формулу?
И как отличается данная функция для одно и двухсторонней гипотезы?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats


def mean_confidence_interval(data, confidence=0.95):
    a = 1.0 * np.array(data)
    n = len(a)
    m, se = np.mean(a), scipy.stats.sem(a)
    h = se * scipy.stats.t.ppf((1 + confidence) / 2., n-1)
    return m, m-h, m+h
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что существуют односторонние и двусторонние доверительные интервалы. Если задан некий уровень значимости alpha, то он отсекает части площади под кривой функции плотности распределения. Если интервал односторонний - то берется просто alpha, а если двусторонний, то он делиться на две части, при этом понятно, что ищется точка отсечения соответствующая значению (1+alpha)/2. (т.е. 95% площади должны уместиться МЕЖДУ этими двумя точками. Например, при alpha =0.95 -  между точками, которые соответствуют 0.025 и 0.975 ).

Открою вам еще один секрет - сама alpha в некоторых случаях (методах, библиотеках, функциях) задается как alpha, а в других -  как 1-alpha. И за этим надо очень внимательно следить.

Формулы можно найти в любом учебнике по статистике. Впрочем, из вопроса не ясно, какую именно формулу вы желаете копировать из учебника сюда.